# Extending the command-line search path without editing the PATH variable

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I want to extend my system search path without appending new directories to `%PATH%`, I am aware of the `App Paths` registry entry put that entry is only being accessed when using `ShellExecuteEx` which the command-line does not use. It there any mechanism on windows to so?

Answer (score 0):

*App Paths* cannot be used for the search path, as far as I know, but you *can* have separate *PATH* defined for both System and User Environment Variables. The search for executables will include all items in both.

If the *length* of System *PATH* is an issue, you can abbreviate by defining another Environment Variable and referencing it, e.g.

Create Environment Variable *PF32* with value *Program File (x86)*

In *PATH*, *C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel* is then shortened to *%PF32%\Intel*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding to the path, I often write a short batch file which sets environment variables for special applications which would unnecessarily extend the path (or add conflicting environment variables).

Here is an example (`run-winvile.bat`) which gives command-line access to a GUI program that is not in `PATH`.  It uses `setlocal` to limit the scope of the changed environment:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set WINVILE_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\VI Like Emacs\bin"
cd %WINVILE_DIR%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :finish  
set WINVILE_EXE=WinVile-wide-ole.exe
if exist %WINVILE_EXE% start %WINVILE_EXE% %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
:finish
endlocal
```

This example gets rid of some conflicting names on the `PATH`:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem trim path to get rid of cygwin
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\com

rem add PERL for vile's builds
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\perl\5.8.5\bin;c:\perl\5.8.5\bin\mswin32-x86-multi-thread

call "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc/vcvarsall.bat" %1
shift
run-winvile %*
endlocal
```